# Old fantasy book about two warring nations and an airship destroyed by a dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel, elves, dragons

I'm looking for a book that was written by two authors about two warring nations of elves and hobbit-like people. The book cover has a small hobbit-like person in a shallow cave with a dragon looming over him. The title escapes me but I think the word *dragon* is in it. The conflict is based around a dragon destroying an air ship and both nations pointing the blame at each other. I know it's a vague description but would love if someone could help me out.

Comment: Approximately when did you read it? Was it new then?

Comment: the book only costs 99 cents now at B&N. I googled it.

Answer (score 4):

It's called *Dragonworld*, by Byron Preiss, Michael Reaves, and Joseph Zucker (Illustrator); and the Illustrations were amazing in that book.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possibly a Dragonlance novel set in the continent of Taladas? They had gnomes that rode in airships and elves, along with nasty dragons.